# Erro em processo de Webscraping vídeos do Youtube no R - NA' does not exist in current working directory

Tags: r, web-scraping, youtube

Eu estou desenvolvendo um trabalho acadêmico em que devo analisar o texto de 25 vídeos selecionados em diversos canais do YouTube. Meu orientador me passou um script sobre como ele está desenvolvendo isso, para que eu trabalhasse nos meus vídeos, mas eu mal terminei e aparece o erro do título: `NA' does not exist in current working directory ...`. Segue o código:

```
library(abjutils)
library(tidytext)
library(reticulate)
reticulate :: use_python("users/agnes/anaconda3/python")
library(spacyr)
spacy_initialize("pt_core_news_sm")
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(stm)
library(tm)
library(ggridges)
library(formattable)
#library(subtools)
options(scipen = 999)
## Preparaando os comandos para baixar as legendas
#Campos bÃ¡sicos
fields_raw <- c("id", "title", "alt_title", "creator", "release_date",
                "timestamp", "upload_date", "duration", "view_count",
                "like_count", "dislike_count", "comment_count")
#Formatando os capos
fields <- fields_raw %>% 
  map_chr(~paste0("%(", ., ")s")) %>% 
  # usar &&& como separador de fields
  paste0(collapse = "&&&") %>% 
  # acrescentar aspas no inicio e no final do string
  paste0('"', ., '"') 
channel_url <- "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rmZv19Iylu4"  

# montar query (comando) do youtube-dl
cmd_ytdl <- str_glue("youtube-dl -o {fields} -i -v -w --skip-download --write-auto-sub --sub-lang pt {channel_url}") 
view(cmd_ytdl)
# acrescentar diretorio
pasta_captions <- "C:/Users/agnes/Documents"  
fs::dir_create(pasta_captions) 
cmd <- str_glue("cd {pasta_captions} && {cmd_ytdl}") 
arquivos_captions <- dir(pasta_captions, pattern = '*.vtt', full.names = TRUE) 
amostra <- arquivos_captions[1] 
read_lines(amostra) [1:12]
```

Answer (score 0):

Oi, não entendi muito bem. você quer os comentários ou as legendas? Se for as legendas, tem um pacote do R para isso.

```
# https://github.com/jooyoungseo/youtubecaption
remotes::install_github("jooyoungseo/youtubecaption")

library(youtubecaption)
# "You can't do data science in a GUI":
url <- "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpbtcsGE0OA"
caption <- get_caption(url)

# Save the caption as an Excel file and open it right away:
get_caption(url = url, savexl = TRUE, openxl = TRUE)

# pegar as legendas em português
url <- "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpbtcsGE0OA"
caption <- get_caption(url,language ="pt")
```

Fonte do exemplo: https://github.com/jooyoungseo/youtubecaption

Se você me permitir, sugiro que você leia esse texto: https://www.curso-r.com/blog/2018-02-21-2cents/